# Anything Slider -jscript run time error-object not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, anythingslider

I am using anything slider http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/,just for the sake that it returns me the current side number,when i import the necessary libraries and work  with notepad ,it works fine...i did the same with Visual studio (2010)(Asp.net framework),and i got the the error,

```
object doesn't support property or method 'anythingSlider'
```

I have added the jquery.js,anythingslider.js and its style sheet!

Intention is to get the current slide number,so any other plugin which returns slide number would also be a solution!

Comment: I have a feeling that your page has two copies of jQuery. Remove one and see if that error goes away

Comment: Nope,It does not works,it points out that object does not support the method anything slider !

Comment: Are you sure the script tag is pointing to the file then? It would be easier to help find the problem if you could share some code or a link to the site.

Comment: Yup,sure here is the tut that i followed  http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/ and also i did add the necessary css files and downloaded js ,i am using jquery 1.7 :)

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from the [wiki documentation](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/wiki/Setup)? The original blog post hasn't been updated with the latest information.